# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'yes'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

When I execute this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO archi(nodo1,nodo2)
SELECT p.nodo,p2.nodo 
FROM polinodo p,polinodo p2 
where p.way=p2.way and p.idpolinodo!=p2.idpolinodo and p.idpolinodo=p2.idpolinodo-1 
and p.way in 
    (SELECT idtag_way 
    FROM tag_way_min where k='highway' and 
    idtag_way in (SELECT idtag_way 
                FROM tag_way_min where k='oneway' and (v=1 or v='true' or v='yes')) )
```

I receive the following error:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'yes'

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the column `v` in your table `tag_way` is numeric, so this part of your `where` clause appears invalid:

```
(v=1 or v='true' or v='yes')
```

Try and modify that part so the conditions match your data type.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a logic problem with asking to retrieve two values for column k from the same row that are different,

```
(SELECT idtag_way 
FROM tag_way_min where k='highway' and 
idtag_way in (SELECT idtag_way 
            FROM tag_way_min where k='oneway' and (v=1 or v='true' or v='yes')
```

I don't see how k can be equal to two values.  Perhaps change it to this:

```
(SELECT idtag_way 
FROM tag_way_min where k='highway' or k='oneway'
idtag_way in (SELECT idtag_way 
            FROM tag_way_min where v=1 or v='true' or v='yes')
```